# Trouble popping a view within a tab bar and nab bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController, which is the second item in a UINavigationBarController. Within the UITabBarController are a couple of views, one of which is a UIViewController subclass called AccountViewController. Got that?

```
Login View Controller -> UIViewController + UITabBarController - > Account View Tab -> Button
```

I want to use a button - Logout - to pop back to the Login view. How would I do that?

Comment: Your login view is a modal view controller right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating the `UITabBarController` within one of the `UIViewControllers` which are part of the string of view controllers within the `UINavigationController` where you have done something similar to this:

```
UITabBarController *mytabs = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:mytabs.view];
mytabs.delegate = self; // This is key to getting back your UINavigationController
```

You can call this from within one of the `UIViewControllers` that are added to your `mytabs.viewControllers` array like so:

```
[[(UIViewController *)self.tabBarController.delegate navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You can also specify if you want it to go to a specific viewController index in the UINavigationController stack ( just in case your Login viewController isn't the next one down or the root view controller ).